# Expected number of throws to get two 6's in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the way to calculate the expected number of fair dice throws in order to get two 6's in a row.

I think the proper solution needs to account for the fact that single six might appear followed by some other number what can happen number of times until two sixes come one after another.

I don't know how to tackle this problem. Can anybody explain the method for this case please.

Comment: My first guess is to model this as a geometric distribution where each trial is a pair of dice throws. I'll need to think carefully about whether this actually gets you what you need though. Thoughts?

Comment: @ Theoretical Economist probability of success  (2 sixes in two throws)  would be $\frac{1}{36}$ if the two throws could be modeled one event then the expectation from the geometric distribution would be $\frac{1}{p}$ which  gives 36 throws. Doesn't it look too simple?

Comment: @Michal That's a bit too simple. Your interpretation is correct if we divide all our throws into pairs of adjacent throws (the first throw is paired with the second, the third with the fourth, the fifth with the sixth, and so on) and we kept going until we had the first such _pair_ of sixes. First of all, in this interpretation, we would expect $36$ _pairs_, i.e. $72$ throws. Second, this does not take into account the possibility that two sixes in a row can happen across pairs (for instance on the second and third throw, or on the fourth and fifth, and so on).

Comment: @Arthur of course -- that's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a trick that is very helpful in cases like these, when you have a process that stops when something specific happens, and we want to know the expected number of steps.

Let $X$ be our random variable (the number of throws to get two sixes in a row). We want $E(X)$. For future reference, I will also invent a new random variable, $Y$, which is basically the same, except that if the *first* throw is a six, then we count that as a success as well. Otherwise we want two sixes in a row.

As we begin, we haven't thrown any sixes yet. We will refer to this as the "scratch state". When we throw the die once, there's a $\frac56$ probability chance that we will end up in the scratch state again, except now we've thrown the die once. There's also a probability of $\frac16$ to end up in a state where our success is measured by the random variable $Y$ instead, except we've thrown the die once.

In other words: There's a $\frac56$ chance of ending up in the scratch state with an additional die throw already done, i.e. there is a $\frac56$ chance that we end up in a situation where the expected number of total throws is $1+E(X)$. There is also a $\frac16$ chance that we throw a $6$, which means we are in a situation where the expexted number of throws to success is $1+E(Y)$. We can put this into algebraic form the following way:
$$
E(X) = \frac56(1+E(X)) + \frac16(1+E(Y))
$$
Now, in oder to solve this, we need to find $E(Y)$. We will do a similar analysis there: There is a $\frac56$ chance of going back to the scratch state, except we've thrown the die once. There is also a $\frac16$ probability of our next throw being the winning throw. This gives us
$$
E(Y) = \frac56(1+E(X)) + \frac16(1)
$$
Now we have a system of two equations and the two unknowns $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$, which means we are able to solve and find our $E(X)$.

Comment: @ Arthur  from the two equations I got $E(X)=48$  and $E(Y)=41$

Comment: I got [$E(X) = 42, E(Y) = 36$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+5*(1%2Bx)%2F6+%2B+(1%2By)%2F6,+y+%3D+5*(1%2Bx)%2F6+%2B+1%2F6). I might've just typed it in wrong, though.

Comment: @ Arthur at first I was trying to create the tree  but I was getting infinite number of paths which where infinite also. If my understanding is correct, I see analogy between the equations you presented and the tree I created up to the second branch $1up \frac{1}{6} \ (6) \  2up \ \frac{1}{6} \ (6) \ 2 \ down  \ \frac{5}{6} \ (1-5)$ and then the other half of the tree  $1 \ down \  \frac{5}{6} \ (1-5) \  2up \ \frac{1}{6} \ (6) \ 2 \ down \  \frac{5}{6} \ (1-5)$ . Did you create those two equations having in mind such a tree? is it correct reasoning?

Comment: @ Arthur  your result is correct  $E(X)=42$  and   $E(Y)=36$

Comment: I don't know exactly how your tree description works, but yes, you could say I had a tree like that in mind. It will be infinite, but it will also be so-called _self-similar_. What I mean by that is that every subtree that starts at the "scratch state" is identical, and every tree that starts at the $Y$-state is identical. From that one may derive the two equations I've written above.

Comment: To obtain two consecutive sixes you can: (I) Throw a six followed by another six, and you are done, or (II) Throw a six followed by something else, and start again, or (III) Throw something else, and start again. $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) &= \tfrac 1{36}(2)+\tfrac 5{36}(\mathsf E(X)+2)+\tfrac {5}{6}(\mathsf E(X)+1) \\ \therefore\quad\mathsf E(X)& = 42\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp That's what I did, except I separated out the "Throw a six and hope for another six" as a separate state.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it will be clearer if we proceed step by step. We shall denote a six by $S$

By the geometric distribution, expected number of trials for first $S,\;\;e_1 = 6$

Then $\frac16$ chance of getting $SS$, else back to scratch, so $e_2 = 6 +\frac16\cdot1 + \frac56(e_2 +1) \to\; e_2 = 42$

*Added*

We can proceed similarly for, say, $SSS$
$e_3 = 42 + \frac16\cdot1 + \frac56(e_3+1) \to\;e_3 = 258$